# CSS and barCode

Tags: html, css, barcode

Hello I am working with the font I2of5nt because I need to create a barCode in a html.
I wrote in my css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'I2of5nt';

  /* for IE */
  src: url(template/css/I2of5nt.ttf) format ('ttf');

  /* non-IE */
  src: local("I2of5nt"), url(template/css/I2of5nt.ttf) format("truetype"); 
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal; 
}

.barCode{
    font-family:'I2of5nt';
}
```

And in the html I have:

```
<div class="barCode">12312312</div>
```

But it doesn't show the barcode, any idea of what is going on? It seems that I should write another parameter, but I don't really know.

Thanks

Comment: you might need programming help not designing...

Comment: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: @Gonzalo I successfully get the bar code on all browser expect IE (checked at my machine). I tried to reproduce a DEMO for you in `jsfiddle` but it doesn't convert text into the real bar code. so I suggest you use a dynamic images which will be generate from server side. hope this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240948/web-pages-and-barcode-fonts or might this link helpful for you. http://www.barcoderesource.com/jquerybarcode.shtml

Answer (score 0):

So probably you are using your @font-face wrong.

Best way is to compile it to a webfont trough a compiler like fontsquirrel.com or fontprep (for mac). Your code should look something like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('MyFont.eot');
  src: url('MyFont.svg#e6614ac1ffeb97962de474601fd3ce1d') format('svg'),
       url('MyFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('MyFont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('MyFont.ttf')  format('truetype');
  font-style:   normal;
  font-weight:  700;
}
```

Comment: what is  `e6614ac1ffeb97962de474601fd3ce1d` ?

Comment: It's the key fontprep uses. Fontsquirrel for example uses another key

Comment: I placed the ttf file into the same folder where the css is located. And I request the font with url ('font-name.ttf'); Is that right? or should I use some other kind of path?

Comment: Have you read my answer? Because if so, the question of only using the ttf would be rather weird.